# Is it possible to update or delete a particular field in elasticsearch 2.4.1 using Update_by_query?

Tags: elasticsearch

i have document in this format:

```
"universities": {
                      "number": 1,
                      "state": [
                         {
                            "Name": "michigan",
                            "country": "us",
                            "code": 5696
                         },                          
                         {
                            "Name": "seatle",
                            "country": "us",
                            "code": 5695
                         }
                      ]
                   }
```

I have to update the the "Name" field where seatle to Denmark in all the documents in the index ?

Is it possible using update_by_query?

I tried it using update_by_query but it is updating all the Name fields rather than updating only for Seatle. 
In the same way how can i able to delete the particular "Name" field where seatle is present in state array?

I tried deleting a particular field using

```
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.universities.state.remove{ it.Name== findName}",
    "params": {
      "findName": "seatle"
    }
  }
}
```

it is throwing error like :

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
        "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_'"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
    "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_'"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
"script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.universities.state.findAll{ it.Name == findName}.each{it.Name = newName}",
    "params": {
      "findName": "seatle",
      "newName": "Denmark"
    }
  }
}
```

First we iterate over the list and find all the elements that have the desired name and then we iterate on the filtered list to update those elements with the new name

Comment: I think you have to change `it.name` as `it.Name`. So, that i can accept your answer

Comment: Oops, I missed the uppercase `N`, fixed it

Comment: Is it the same way i have to apply for deleting a particular field too.

Comment: You'd do `ctx._source.universities.state.removeAll{ it.Name == findName}` instead

Comment: Thanks..Val by using above code all the fields in the matched list will go what about particular field in that matched list?i tried giving it as `remove` rather than `removeAll` it shows no effect..